# PHP: Cookie read incorrectly or fault in logic?

Tags: php, cookies

I was trying to make a "simple" guessing game in PHP. However, it seems that when the user presses the "Submit" button to submit the answer, then at some (seemingly random) moments, in stead of seeing the question again and seeing the correct answer, a different question and answer is displayed. I've got a feeling that the issue is in the logic or maybe the cookie that stores the question number. Here's a snip:

```
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
    $questionNo = $_POST['q'];
    $text = str_replace("\\", "", $_POST['ans']);
    $text = ltrim(rtrim($text, "'"), "'");
    $button = "Next one";
    $action = "window.location='game.php';";
    $verify = True;
} else {
    $verify = False;
    $answered = unserialize(urldecode($_COOKIE['answered']));
    if (gettype($answered) == 'boolean') {
        $answered[0] = "";
    }

    while (True) {
        if (array_search($questionNo, $answered) > 0 && count($answered) < ($numberOfQuestions + 1)) {
        $questionNo = $questionNo + 1;
        $questionNo = ($questionNo > $numberOfQuestions ? $questionNo - $numberOfQuestions : $questionNo);
    } else {
        $answered[count($answered)] = $questionNo;
        setcookie('answered', urlencode(serialize($answered)));
        break;
    }
}
```

The longer code I've put to PasteBin, [available here](http://pastebin.com/E4wVcFQk). I've just in case also pasted the SQL data, [which is here](http://pastebin.com/JApzfyWs).

Thanks ahead for any ideas!